# Using Raised or Rose in different contexts?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

You use *raised* in some situations, like

> I raised my hand

but in other situations,

> I rose early in the morning

you use *rose*. Is there a common rules for using *rose* or *raised*?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that **raised** is the past of **raise** and **rose** is the past of **rise**.

Comment: The "lack of research" reason for closure means: you should have looked for the two words in a dictionary before asking here.  Then, if still unsure, ask the question including what you found in the dictionary.

Comment: @GEdgar You probably meant to post this comment to the question not to the answer.